# Edit suggestion audit page displays incorrect information

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity, suggested-edits, revisions-list

I just approved an [edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/5541), or at least I *thought* I did. When I refreshed the page, the summary or audit page indicates that I actually *rejected* it and it appears that I was the only user required to do so!

[image: Apparently I rejected an edit]

The edit was **not** to one of my posts, so I'm not sure why only one vote was required. But stranger yet was that I intended to *approve* the edit, not reject it. I thought I must have foolishly clicked the wrong button, but a visit to the recent activity in my profile shows this not to be the case:

[image: My recent activity, indicating that I approved the edit]

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999948/problem-in-making-the-grammar-accept-different-range-of-numeric-values) also shows the edit was not approved, so it appears that only my profile that is out of sync.

What just happened? Is there a bug in the system, or did I just bugger up? It was a perfectly valid and necessary edit, and I hate to be the one to have rejected it, especially when I didn't intend to do so. Is there some way that the original editor could have *canceled* the edit, or someone else could have overrode their edit?

Comment: We know what happened; we're discussing the best the way to fix it now.

Comment: Also, you didn't do anything wrong (you voted to approve) - no buggering up was performed :)

Comment: @Jarrod: Thanks for the update; that's reassuring. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what happened:

1. anonymous user submitted a suggested edit
2. Ted Hopp submitted [his edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4999948/revisions)
3. suggested edit was auto-rejected

Ted was able to submit because he had loaded the edit page *before* the suggested edit was created.

**I've changed the auto-reject behavior to deletion**: users with full edit privileges will have their edits saved, deleting any pending suggested edits and any approve/reject votes.  This will only occur if the edit page was loaded before a suggestion exists.

This change is live.

As to [your activity stream](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray?tab=activity&filter=reviews), it shows how you voted on a particular edit, not that it was the *binding vote*.  I'm adding a tooltip on the `approved` or `rejected` text to help clarify this, e.g. hovering over `rejected` will display "voted to reject this suggested edit."

This tooltip change will be pushed out tomorrow.

Comment: @Cody - also, I've deleted the rejected suggested edit referenced in your question, unbuggering your activity timeline :)

Comment: Thanks for investigating this and providing such a thorough answer. The previous behavior makes sense once explained, and I agree with the modifications you've made. Although, I understood what the activity stream was showing, and I'm not sure that the tooltip would have mitigated my confusion (although it couldn't hurt). The problem was simply that the suggested edit page listed me as the sole rejecter when that wasn't the case. Either deleting the edit suggestion entirely (as you've done), or showing it rejected by Community would be more logical.

Comment: @Cody - we're still tweaking lots of things around suggested edits; better info around activity is coming!