# Failed an audit for a post I never reviewed

Tags: bug, status-norepro, suggested-edits, review-audits

I was reviewing some suggested edits, when suddenly I was informed that I [failed an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1552671). I totally understand that there are audits, I have seen them before, but in this case I did not review that post, or hit the Approve button -- I received the "audit failed" notice without first receiving that same post for review. So, either there is a bug with the audit, or some IDs got mixed up or something. The only non-bug related situation I can think of is that somehow the Approve button was pressed without me even noticing, which I would say is also a bug.

It might be nothing, but I felt a duty to make a report; maybe others have had wrong audits hit them too.

([Another *possibly* similar bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79341/edit-suggestion-audit-page-displays-incorrect-information?rq=1))

Comment: I don't think this is the same bug (which is good if they thought they fixed it 2 years ago), since in this case your Activity tab shows that you approved it and in that case the Audit page and the Activity page showed opposite actions.

Answer (score 1):

Given the timing, it does appear that this was unintentional - right now, we're gonna blame your ISP.

If this happens again, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Glad to hear its not a bug of yours.